# Is it possible to add the crashlytics api key without using androidmanifest.xml file?

Tags: crashlytics

Android: 
Is it possible to add the **Crashlytics** api key without using androidmanifest.xml file? If possible where I need to add the api key in my code and which method will be help to set the api key in my app. Because, I need to add the multiple Crashlytics account dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I discussed with crashlytics support team, we cannot add more than one crashlytics account in dynamically. The only one option is androidmanifest.xml configuration. we cannot change this in run time.